# Jquery crop plugin, don't know if something like this exists

Tags: jquery, plugins, crop

Let's say i have an area e.g. 200px by 100px. And instead of selecting a crop inside that field, I want the field itself to be the crop area and I drag the image instead of the crop field.

[image: Crop image example]

So you can see the edges of the full image, but you only see the image inside the crop area. You drag the image around and you see the changes within

Comment: As you can see, i'm new here. Thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple little concept. It'll need some refining to make sure you can't drag outside the bounds (if you start your drag on the red bordered div it doesn't apply the containment rule), but this should provide a proof of concept.

http://jsfiddle.net/foxwisp/G7cEP/1/

Basically you just update the position of the mask box so that it isolates, and then update the background image position so it appears to move.

Let me know if you need me to explain it further.

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Thanks a lot mate. Is it me or is there one problem though? The outer image can be dragged down and right, but not up and down from the center. What is causing this?

Comment: Nevermind. It's a function you added to the script :) 
You already helped me a great deal, but do you know how I can now drag the corners of the outer edge of the image to resize the image while the crop is still the same?

Comment: I will post a fiddle tomorrow but the only way I can see it working with the above approach would be using the background-size property to scale the background image on the resize event (which would be implemented with jquery_ui). background size is quite new though.

Comment: Well. as long as it works. Is there no other approach to this e.g. not using the background size :)

Comment: Here is another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/foxwisp/G7cEP/4/ showing a resize concept with a slightly different approach to the original example. Again, I have not included restrictions on the resize/drag so you'll have to implement that to make sure you can't resize it past the mask box, or stretch it beyond the draggable area etc. Proof of concept tho :)